# Changing class to active using JavaScript onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried my best to figure this out myself but to no avail as I'm new to web development. It's probably really basic but I'd really appreciate some help because I'm going around in circles here..

I have a Google map search form (essentially a store locator) and what I've done for the search results is split into two tabs; a list and a map.

What I would like to do is have the map tab always be the active tab when the submit button is pressed in the search form.

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li id="maptab" class="active"><a href="#resmap">Map</a></li>
  <li id="listtab" ><a href="#reslist">List</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="resmap">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="reslist">
    <div id="results">
      <ul class="res-list" id="list"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically for the map items I'm trying to get the code to return to

```
div class="tab-pane active"
```

and

```
li class="active"
```

Presumably I have to add an onclick element to the submit button??

The html for the submit button in the form is

```
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: where is the submit button

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to post up loads of code. In the form the submit button is <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />

Comment: you question is not clear :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I presume you are trying to add the "active" class to that li element:

```
var button = document.getElementById('edit-submit');

button.onclick= function() {

    // this adds the 'active' class to the classes that the element already has
    var maptab = document.getElementById('maptab');

    maptab.className = maptab.className + ' active';
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to do #(but I probably didn't explain myself too well in my original post)

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your problem, it would be great if you could select this answer as the best one :) Thank you!